# How can I improve a PCT?

Tags: patent-applications, uspto, pct, epo, amendment

I have applied for a national patent and then I applied for a PCT claiming priority over the national patent and then I applied for a second national patent with improved content over the PCT just few days before the PCT was published. Now, I want to abandon the PCT and patent the content of the second national application which has improved/added matter over the PCT. Is that possible? I wonder if I can cancel the PCT and claim priority over the second national patent or cancel the PCT and claim priority over the PCT. I do not want to have to prove that my improved/added matter is novel and inventive over the PCT. Please note I am interested to get US and EU patents.

Comment: Don't enter the epo national phase and the pct won't be prior art there. For the US I don't know.

Comment: @DonQuiKong - If the newest application is filed before publication of the PCT how can the epo national stage entry effect it as prior art?

Comment: @GeorgeWhite art 54(3) epc. The EPO considers non- published applications as prior art (only for novelty) only if they are EPO applications. PCT applications count as EPO applications only if nationalized. Afaik the US neither counts non-published foreign applications as prior, but I don't know how they deal with PCT applications that are not nationalized.

Comment: @DonQuiKong thanks but the PCT is now published, so how can it not be prior art in the EPO? Also, I as I mention in my question, I am looking to get EP and US patents.

Comment: It is not prior art for the second application filed prior to publication (subject to the above). By drawing priority from that second application you can go to EP while retaining the filing date.

Comment: @DonQuiKong thanks, would it be possible to apply for a new PCT claiming priority over my second national application (which was filed before the publication of my current PCT)? And then nationalise this new/second PCT?

Comment: @DonQuiKong sorry to understand, I will be able to apply for an EPO (and potentially US) patent now, claiming priority from the second national application (filed before the PCT publication), without having to prove novelty and inventiveness over the PCT as long as I do not proceed with this PCT in the EU/US national phase?

Comment: For epo, yes. For us I don't know. But if you're able to pay a PCT fee, maybe you should be paying a patent attorney.